# Custom font not used in Windows 8 XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I'm trying to use a custom font in a Windows 8 C#-XAML Metro App, but the XAML is ignoring the font.

I use it like that: TextBlock FontFamily="/Assets/fonts/brlnsdb.ttf#Berlin Sans FB Demi"

I added the font to the project (in the Folder: Assets/fonts/), set it's build action to "Content" and the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always".

I also tried to change the path to "ms-appx:/Assets/fonts/brlnsdb.ttf#Berlin Sans FB Demi.

The spelling is correct and the filename and the actual font name are correct too.

Comment: Is it "Berlin Sans FB Demi **Bold**"?

Comment: Yes, but adding the Bold doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "Demi Bold".

```
 <TextBlock FontFamily="/Assets/fonts/BRLNSDB.TTF#Berlin Sans FB" 
           Text="Berlin Sans FB Demi Bold" ...
```

[image]

(postscript)
Above, I mistook.

Windows 8 has the "Berlin Sans FB" font. So, you can write as follows.

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Berlin Sans FB" ...
```

However, the font contained in "/Assets/fonts/BRLNSDB.TTF" is not used by this XAML code. I guess that the font of the same name as a system font cannot be specified in xaml.

Comment: Thank you it works. Strange though as the "name" of the font (the one displayed if I open the file) contains the Demi.

Comment: Very irritating gotcha that the reported font name isn't the one used for targeting. In my case '#The Serif Black' only worked with '#The Serif'.